# Oracle equivalent of sp_rename in SQL Server

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I am trying to rename a column of multiple tables in Oracle using a cursor over a table that has all the information of other table.

In SQL Server I was able to do it correctly using `sp_rename`. I am not able to find an equivalent in Oracle.

I tried with alter table but my table names are in variable so I am not able to do it. I am using:

```
execute immediate alter table var_table_name rename var_col to var_new_col
```

Can anyone provide a method that is similar to `sp_rename` in Oracle or any other method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>*Community Wiki answer containing the solution given by [Justin Cave](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/555/justin-cave) in a question comment*</sub>

---

`execute immediate` takes a string.  The snippet you posted has no strings in it.  You'd need to assemble the appropriate string and then pass that to `execute immediate`.  Something like:

```
execute immediate 'alter table ' || var_table_name || ' rename ' || 
    var_col || ' to ' || var_new_col`.
```

Of course, you probably want to put that in a local variable so that if/when it fails you can log the actual SQL statement.